# TYPO3: Adding different block formats to RTE

Tags: typo3, typoscript, rte

In the RTE there are a few predefined block formats like "Headings", "paragraph" and so. Is it possible to do new block formats, and customize the markup that wraps them?

Im doing a newsletter and I would like to use tables around each paragraph

Comment: Actually if you're using TemplaVoila, you can prepare template for newsletter and use FCE to wrap parts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a button called `Insert custom element` and there you can add custom *para-templates*  for RTE, however it's possible that you need to enable it and add new 'items'.

[Here](http://www.typo3-lisardo.de/home/blog-post/2010/09/01/custom-tags-im-rte.html) (DE) in section ***Einfügen über User-Elemente*** you have a description for that. Presented snippets should be placed in the PageTS of highest (root) page.

Comment: I did found that page, and it seemed exactly like what I needed, but for some reason, when I click to "save", the format disappears. Maybe I couldnt understand it well, since its in German and Im not precisely fluent

Comment: Hard to say, sometimes RTE configuring is annoying anyway believe me that works in general (I'm using in in few places, butI don't speak German, so I cannot verify if description hasn't any bug). Also make sure that your template hasn't any bug (unclosed tags or something) and make sure you're clearing RTE cache as well.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in Page TSconfig:

```
RTE.default.userElements {
  10 = Various elements
  10 {
    1 = Table
    1.description = Wrap in a table
    1.content = <table><tr><td>|</td></tr></table>
  }
}
```

To enable the "Insert custom element" button:

```
RTE.default.showButtons := addToList(user)
RTE.default.hideButtons := removeFromList(user)
```

**Edit**: You might need to fiddle with the parser to allow certain tags or attributes. I think this one did it for my case:

```
RTE.default.proc.HTMLparser_db.allowTags = html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td
```

Source: [htmlarea manual](http://typo3.org/extension-manuals/rtehtmlarea_manual/4.7.0/view/4/4/) and [this snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/23427/)

Comment: When i click on "save", the markup of the userElements get deleted

Comment: I just edited my answer in response to the comment below (I cannot comment anywhere yet). Might be about the parser. I had to play around quite a bit to get it how I wanted it. Also, I was able to confirm on my test site that it works, although on an ancient Typo3 4.3.5.

Comment: The problem seems to lie with the tag <font> even though it is in the list of allowed tags...

Comment: How complex is your HTML wrap? You use the font tag? What happens if you use inline styles instead?
BTW: hope you noticed my typo above in the last snippet with the two equals signs (corrected).

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :) The markup is complex enough, since im building a newsletter. Includes a <table> with 2 columngs, an <img> and <font>

Comment: Since <font> is outdated, it's probably stripped by default. Try some [transformation settings](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/RteApi/Transformations/PageTsconfig/Index.html) (esp. HTMLparser_*) to allow it, but I'd recommend rewriting at least it to inline CSS.
What about using layouts? This way you can wrap the whole content element: [link1](http://www.includemedia.de/en/magazine/layouts-in-typo3/), [link2](http://www.typo3wizard.com/en/snippets/cool-stuff-typoscript/using-the-layout-field-in-tt-content-and-pages.html)

Comment: It was already too complicated find a code that worked on my newsletter. I can't really adapt much more.

Comment: Getting the parser to accept deprecated tags is a whole another story, one that I never attempted. Here's how Typo3Buddy [allowed <u> and <s> tags](http://typo3buddy.reijkman.nl/typoscript/typoscript-snips/underline-and-strike-in-rte/) which might also work for <font>. Otherwise, a simple replacement of <font> with <span>+appropriate styles shouldn't be disruptive at all. I hope your initial wrap question has been answered, the <font> issue can be further discussed in chat.